# Combo box doesn't show the current data and the drop down list after clicking the edit button

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a form from which brand can be added and edited but from different buttons but button for another function is disabled while operating one.

How to make the already selected items appear in the brand and category combo box and how to make the list of all the items are shown?

[This is the form after the edit button is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUrKQ.png)

This is the code of the form.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class AddProduct : Form
    {
        private SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
        private SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        private DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
        private SqlDataReader dr;
        private ProductList plist;

        public AddProduct(ProductList pl)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.MyConnection());
            plist = pl;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            tbPID.Clear();
            tbDesc.Clear();
            tbPrice.Clear();
            cbBrand.Text = "";
            cbCategory.Text = "";
            tbPrice.Focus();
            btnSave.Enabled = true;
            btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
        }

        public void LoadCategory()
        {
            cbCategory.Items.Clear();
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT category FROM tblCategory", cn);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                cbCategory.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        public void LoadBrand()
        {
            cbBrand.Items.Clear();
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT brand FROM tblBrand", cn);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                cbBrand.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }

        private void AddProduct_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save this product?", " ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    string bid = "";
                    string cid = "";

                    cn.Open();
                    cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM tblBrand where brand like'" + cbBrand.Text + "'", cn);
                    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();
                    if (dr.HasRows)  bid = dr[0].ToString(); 
                    dr.Close();
                    cn.Close();

                    cn.Open();
                    cm = new SqlCommand("select id from tblCategory where category like'" + cbCategory.Text + "'", cn);
                    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();
                    if (dr.HasRows)  cid = dr[0].ToString(); 
                    dr.Close();
                    cn.Close();

                    cn.Open();
                    cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblProduct(pcode, pdesc, bid, cid, price)VALUES(@pcode, @pdesc, @bid, @cid, @price)", cn);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", tbPID.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", bid);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdesc", tbDesc.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", cid);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", tbPrice.Text);
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Product has been added successfully.");
                    Clear();
                    plist.LoadProducts();
                    this.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear(); 
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to update this product?", " ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    string bid = "";
                    string cid = "";

                    cn.Open();
                    cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM tblBrand where brand like'" + cbBrand.Text + "'", cn);
                    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();
                    if (dr.HasRows) bid = dr[0].ToString();
                    dr.Close();
                    cn.Close();

                    cn.Open();
                    cm = new SqlCommand("select id from tblCategory where category like'" + cbCategory.Text + "'", cn);
                    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();
                    if (dr.HasRows) cid = dr[0].ToString();
                    dr.Close();
                    cn.Close();

                    cn.Open();
                    cm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblProduct SET pdesc=@pdesc, bid=@bid, cid=@cid, price=@price where pcode like @pcode", cn);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", tbPID.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", bid);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdesc", tbDesc.Text);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", cid);
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", double.Parse(tbPrice.Text));

                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Product has been updated successfully.","Product Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    Clear();
                    plist.LoadProducts();
                    this.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the methods `LoadBrand` and `LoadCategory` called? I do not see anywhere in the code where those methods are called. And they appear to be loading the combo boxes with data.

Comment: I removed the "visual-studio" tag because this shall be used only for question regarding the development environment itself.